# Launching application on iPhone for non-developer

Tags: iphone

Say I have created an application, and I want my friend to have it. (I am not going to submit it to the App Store; I just want my friend to run it on her iPhone).

I am not going to give the code, but is there any way I could create something like an `.exe` file, where she could launch it easily ?

Note, I used the word `exe`, to mean that I am looking for a easy way for a non-developer to launch the application on his/her iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an .ipa (archive) of your app.
But if you want your friend to use the app, you have to add his UDID to the provisioning profile. Minor detail is that this profile expires after (I think) a month, so you have to regenerate the profile and install it again on your friend's device.
 Or you can "get" yourself an iOS enterprise account to create "in-house" applications.

Answer (score 4):

You so want to sign up for [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). It really makes that process easy. No need to worry about UUIDs at all. It is all done via emails and links.

Comment: Need i specify the UDID of the device my friend is using ? Or i just have to upload it to testflight and it takes care of the rest ?

Comment: Testflight does all that for you. It sends an email that the friend opens on their phone. The click it and it does all the UUID stuff. Very easy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run your app on a device, any device, you have to have a paid Apple Developer account and have the device's udid added to a provisioning profile. This provisioning profile is used when your app is compiled. To share an app (a .ipa file not an .exe file) you need have an account, add his device udid to an ad-hoc distribution profile and build your app with this profile. You then send the app to your friend along with the provisioning profile and he can drag them into iTunes and install the app on his device.